# Build gradle failed in all gradle versions

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, gradle

I had the Build Gradle Failed problem and tried to switch to several versions of gradle, I always changed the version in the .gradle files, I tried to follow several videos and forums and could not solve this problem
I use Unity 2021.3.5 LTS
In this project I created today I just changed a skybox and added a camera script, I didn't install anything different

Sequence of errors that appear to me:

> Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 7 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
>
> You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
>
> See https://docs.gradle.org/8.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
>
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:processEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

> A problem occurred evaluating project ':launcher'.
> org/gradle/initialization/BuildCompletionListener
>
> Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 6s
> Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
>
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:processEvent (int,intptr,bool&)

> CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.
> C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2021.3.5f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle-8.1.1\lib\gradle-launcher-8.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"
>
> stderr[
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> Where:
> Build file 'C:\UnityProjetos\ChessExperience\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\Mono2x\Gradle\launcher\build.gradle' line: 1
>
> What went wrong:
> A problem occurred evaluating project ':launcher'.
> org/gradle/initialization/BuildCompletionListener
>
> Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> BUILD FAILED in 6s
> Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
> ]
> stdout[
> Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 7 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
>
> Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
>
> You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
>
> See https://docs.gradle.org/8.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
> ]
> exit code: 1
> UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <66a36f4eb7c24c42bf1d8c5cb4777570>:0)
> UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <66a36f4eb7c24c42bf1d8c5cb4777570>:0)
> UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at <66a36f4eb7c24c42bf1d8c5cb4777570>:0)
> UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at <66a36f4eb7c24c42bf1d8c5cb4777570>:0) UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <66a36f4eb7c24c42bf1d8c5cb4777570>:0)
> Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed
> UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at <66a36f4eb7c24c42bf1d8c5cb4777570>:0)
> UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <66a36f4eb7c24c42bf1d8c5cb4777570>:0)
> UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <66a36f4eb7c24c42bf1d8c5cb4777570>:0)
> Rethrow as BuildFailedException: Exception of type 'UnityEditor.Build.BuildFailedException' was thrown.
> UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.CancelPostProcess.AbortBuild (System.String title, System.String message, System.Exception ex) (at <66a36f4eb7c24c42bf1d8c5cb4777570>:0)
> UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at <66a36f4eb7c24c42bf1d8c5cb4777570>:0)
> UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, AndroidPlayerBuildProgram.Data.AndroidPlayerBuildProgramOutput buildProgramOutput) (at <66a36f4eb7c24c42bf1d8c5cb4777570>:0)
> UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor.PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs args, UnityEditor.BuildProperties& outProperties) (at <66a36f4eb7c24c42bf1d8c5cb4777570>:0)
> UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer.Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup targetGroup, UnityEditor.BuildTarget target, System.Int32 subtarget, System.String installPath, System.String companyName, System.String productName, System.Int32 width, System.Int32 height, UnityEditor.BuildOptions options, UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry usedClassRegistry, UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport report) (at <1f0be198f5164d2489de92f22c998266>:0)
> UnityEngine.GUIUtility:processEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

I tried to follow several videos and forums and could not solve this problem

Comment: The errors seem to relate to Unity's build process specifically, not Gradle, so it looks more like a Unity problem. If you made changes that broke your build, that's a good sign of where your problem lies! I don't know anything about Unity, but maybe there's a problem with your camera script?

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: The build works perfectly in any other non-mobile application